# Creating fixed dimension Halide pipelines

Tags: c++, halide

My file is compiled ahead of time.
I calculate small Regions out of an Image. Over these i'd like to normalize with overlap. Therefore i a Func thats calculating the factor with Reduction Domains. 
Afterwards i try to calculate normalized Regions that are overlapping. The result therefore has a bigger size. As long as the Func i realize is the small Regions its working, when i try compile to b its not working anymore as the result has to have another dimension as the one needed for c.
Is there any way to set dimensions for a Func depending on in- or output buffer dimension? Or do you know any other workarounds?

```c++
    Func    cells("cells");
    c(g_x,g_y,g_i) = 0.0f;

    // this is working 
    c(g_x, g_y, g_i) = ...

    Var c_x("c_x"), c_y("c_y");
    // calculate normalization factor
    Func norm_factor("norm_factor");
    // cpb means cells per block
    RDom cbd (0,cpb,0,cpb,0, nBins);

    Expr    lx = c_x + cbd.x; 
    Expr    ly = c_y + cbd.y; 
    Expr    lz = cbd.z;

    norm_factor(c_x, c_y)       = 1 / sqrt(Halide::sum(c(lx, ly, lz) * c(lx, ly, lz)) + eta*eta );

    // Caculate the normalized Blocks
    Func b("blocks");

    b(c_x,c_y,g_i)     = 0.f;
    b(c_x, c_y, g_i)   = norm_factor(g_x, g_y) * c(g_x,g_y,g_i);

    b.compile_to_file("halide",args);
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, `b` is defined using `c_x, c_y, g_i` but those `Vars` are not used in the definition.

Possibly you meant to say

```
b(c_x, c_y, g_i)= norm_factor(c_x, c_y) * c(c_x, c_y, g_i);
```

or for only one `b` value per block

```
b(c_x, c_y, g_i)   = norm_factor(c_x * cpb, c_y * cpb) * c(c_x * cpb, c_y * cpb, g_i);
```